# How to make Safari download a file without the "Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted" error

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari, content-disposition

A jQuery ajax post request is used to fetch and download a file.

The response to fetching the document has `content-disposition` header set to `attachment; filename=example.csv`.

On Safari, the request is causing the following error: `Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted`.

The document is downloaded correctly, but because of this error, the status property of the `jqxhr` response object is set to `0`. Because the client code is using this status code to determine if a network error has occurred, the client code behaves as if the download failed.

How can I avoid Safari raising the `Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted` error?